# Store list of One-To-Many relation Using ObjectBox?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, relation, objectbox

I get a json like below from server:

```
  { "customers": [
    {
        "customer_name": "name1",
        "orders_list": [
            {
                "order_id": "1111111",
                "order_type": "a",
                "order_date": "11/02/2020 "
            },
            {
                "order_id": "1111112",
                "order_type": "b",
                "order_date": "11/02/2020 "
            },
            {
                "order_id": "1111113",
                "order_type": "c",
                "order_date": "11/02/2020 "
            }
        ]
    },
    //more customers
]
```

}

I get it using Retrofit and want to store it with Objectbox.

Customer entity:

```
  @Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id long id;

    @SerializedName("customer_name")
    private String  customer_name;

    @SerializedName("array_of_matchs")
    @Transient
    public List<Order> orders_list;

    @Backlink
    public ToMany<Order> orders;

   //constructor , getters , setters ,...
}
```

Order Entity:

public class Order {

```
    @Id
    public long id;

    @SerializedName("order_id")
    private int  order_id;

    @SerializedName("order_type")
    private String  order_type;

    @SerializedName("order_date")
    private String  order_date;

    public ToOne<Customer> customer;
  //constructor , getters , setters ,...
}
```

Gson convertor returns a `List` of `Customer`s with all his orders.I tried to store customers as below :

```
  customersBox.put(list_of_customers_get_from_retrofit);
```

And orders :

```
for (Customer each_customer : list_of_customers_get_from_retrofit ) {
      orderBox.put(each_customer.orders_list);
}
```

Then when i checked boxes with [Data Browser](https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser) ,all `customerToOneRelationId`s set to 0 .
What's wrong with that?

In such case, how do we make a relation between  the `customer` and his `Order`s List?
How to store orders in right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to set targets manually :

```
 for (Customer each_customer : list_of_customers_get_from_retrofit ) {
     for (Order each_order : each_customer.orders_list ) {
       each_order.customer.setTarget(each_customer);
       orderBox.put(each_order);
     }
}
```

Thanks to this [repository](https://github.com/alanamado/BakingApp) (This is useful for any Objectbox newbie like me).